# How or why does passing by reference overwrite other references with PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, byref

Could someone explain to me why by-reference variable passing behaves in the way I am witnessing?

Here is a method from a controller I am working on:

```
public function view($view,$context=array()){
    // <snip>
    foreach($context as $a=>$b){
        $$a = $b;
    }
    // <snip>
}
```

It copies the data `$context` array into the local scope so that when the view is called (included) it can access the elements.

```
$foo->method(); // first thing
$bar->method(); // second thing
```

Being a bit of a fusspot, I wanted to work with the actual objects rather than copies (which just seemed wasteful) so I changed it to this:

```
public function view($view,$context=array()){
    // <snip>
    foreach($context as $a=>$b){
        $$a =& $b;
    }
    // <snip>
}
```

That was when I witnessed something I was not expecting.

```
$foo->method(); // second thing!!
$bar->method(); // second thing
```

In the test case two objects are passed to the view which then outputs relevant data. When passing by reference rather than by value both variables ended up with references to the second object.

I did not expect that to happen. I would very much like someone to explain to me why that happened. I've probably missed something obvious so please educate me.

In case it is relevant (I suspect it might be but I am not sure).

The method is called like this:

```
$data = array();
$data['foo'] =& $this->module()->get_foo();
$data['bar'] =& $this->module()->get_bar();
$this->view('nameOfView',$data);
```

The gets return by-reference in this instance so the **&** here is probably overkill. Again, I am not as certain as I would like to be. For the purposes of this question I just *really* want to understand what is going on with the reference overwriting in the view method but feel free to school me on anything else I should know but clearly don't.

Comment: I can't explain in detail right now, but in general, using references of foreach loop variables is asking for trouble. Note though, that objects are not copied. If you have an array of objects, the array itself is copied, including the *references to* the objects, but the objects themselves are still the original objects, so your optimization is useless. I think in your second loop, you are replacing all items in the array with *a reference to a reference to* the last object in the iteration.

Comment: I only read up to "Being a bit of a fusspot, I wanted to work with the actual objects rather than copies". Two observations: a) [extract()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) and b) [Objects and references](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) (i.e. you're not working on copies of an instance when you assign $$a=$b) - maybe that makes your question a non-issue (though maybe interesting)

Comment: I too used to be a fusspot worrying about excessive copying.  But then I learned that the "copies" are "lazy copies", meaning the copy is made only if and when you actually modify your "copy" of the data.  Until then, you are reading the same data in memory (and in most cases I found I was rarely modifying my input parameters).

Comment: doesn't [extract — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) do the same thing as your function?

Comment: The explanation for the references all having the `// second thing!`, is that there i only one variable `$b`, in the foreach - it's value changes, the reference to it doesn't change. PHP references can be 'interesting' ;-/

Comment: I did not know about extract(). Feeling like a total noob now, a happy noob, though.

Comment: @RyanVincent That makes perfect sense. It took me a moment - had to read your comment twice - but I get it. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the variable `$b` is being reused by the `foreach` loop.
And as `$b` is reassigned, so are all references to it.

Simple example:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$c = [];
foreach($a as $b)
{
    $c[] = &$b;
}
print_r($c);
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
)
```

You can even take it a step further and do an assignment after your `foreach` loop:

```
$b = 'derp';
```

which will turn your array into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => derp
    [1] => derp
    [2] => derp
)
```

Now, as stated twice in the comments so far, there is a function called [`extract()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), which seems to have been made exactly for what you're trying to do, and which is the way I suggest to go with.

But for the sake of completeness, it is fairly simple to "fix" your code.
There are two ways to do this:

- Make `$b` a reference instead of a copy.
  You can do that by using `$a as &$b` as argument to `foreach`:

  ```
  $a = [1, 2, 3];
  $c = [];
  foreach($a as &$b)
  {
      $c[] = &$b;
  }
  print_r($c);
  ```
- Break the reference to `$b` before it is reassigned.
  You can do that by calling `unset($b);` at the end of your loop:

  ```
  $a = [1, 2, 3];
  $c = [];
  foreach($a as $b)
  {
      $c[] = &$b;
      unset($b);
  }
  print_r($c);
  ```

Both of the above will then give you what you initially expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Note that when using the first way and you modify `$a` after this, `$c` might change as well, but not always.
For example, a direct assignment (`$a[0] = 5;`) will affect `$c` (`$c[0] == 5`).
`$c` remains unaffected by any other action on `$a` (as far as I can tell), but after messing with indices in `$a` (as with `array_shift()` or `shuffle()`), `$c[1]` might be a reference to `$a[0]`, etc.

If you don't want a headache, just go with `extract()`.

Comment: That's a solid answer. I understand what was happening now and, yes, will indeed be going with extract.

Comment: being 'picky' - there is only one variable $b so everything gets to point to it. It contains the last value of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @RyanVincent But there are multiple variables, each of which was called `$b` at some point. :P

Comment: The `foreach` loop variable can hold a reference to the 'looped object' see `foreach($a as &$b)` - note the `&$b`. Alas, That didn't happen here. What happened was that a reference to the loop variable `$b` was taken. So, everyone gets a refeerence to the 'loop variable' _not what it is pointing to!_.  So everyone `sees` the last value that the 'loop variable - $b' has. Which is the last value in the loop.